# Stacked bar charts ggplot2 - reorder fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm plotting a stacked bar chart using ggplot2. I've created a dataframe (df_car) with the variables `car_make`, `color` and `proportion`, the latter being numerical. There are 20 types of `car_make` which go along the x-axis, and 4 of `color` which go as fills. The proportion for each `car_make` adds up to 1.

I didn't want the `car_make` in alphabetical order so I re-ordered it:

```
df_car$car_make <- factor(df_car$car_make, levels = c("toyota", "ford", "mercedes", etc.)
```

Then I re-ordered the fill levels:

```
df_car$color <- factor(df_car$color, levels = c("red", "white", "black", "silver")
```

I plot the stacked bar plot:

```
bp_car<- ggplot(df_car, aes(x=car_make, y=proportion, fill=color)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

The x-axis comes out as I specified. But the order of the bar fills remains alphabetical...only the order of the legend responds and comes out as specified. Performing...

```
levels(df_car$color)
```

gives...

> "red", "white", "black", "silver"

How can I get the bar fills to re-order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a data column with color names in it (ggplot is different from base graphics in this way). Once your car levels are ordered appropriately (as you've done), you need to set a fill color scale

```
bp_car <- ggplot(df_car, aes(x = car_make, y = proportion, fill = car_make)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "white", "black", "silver"))
```